# Position: absolute content above scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:
I have a table, in that table I have a bunch of cells. Some of the cells have tooltips.

The tooltip appears if the user hovers over the given cell.
The twist is that this table has a scrollbar on the bottom, which goes from left ot right. It is because the content is too big to fit in the screen.

If I have a position : absolute for the tooltip without a relative parent, it shows the content above the scrollbar (readable), but does not follow the scrollbar.

If I have position: absolute for the tooltip with a relative parent, it follows the scrollbar, but hides the content.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
     <style>
     thead > tr > td {
      background-color: grey;
      width: 150px;
      height: 30px;
     }
     
     table{
      table-layout: fixed;
     }
     
     .tooltipWrapper{
      position:relative;
     }
     
     .tooltip{
      position: absolute;
      display:none;
      top: 10px;
      background-color: green;
     }
     
     .tooltipWrapper:hover .tooltip{
      display:block;
     }
     
     .contentWrapper{
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
     }
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="contentWrapper">
     <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 6</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
        <td>Column 11</td>
        <td>Column 12</td>
        <td>Column 13</td>
        <td>Column 14</td>
        <td>Column 15</td>
        <td>Column 16</td>
        <td>Column 17</td>
        <td>Column 18</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 1-1</td>
        <td>Content 1-2</td>
        <td>Content 1-3</td>
        <td>Content 1-4</td>
        <td>Content 1-5</td>
        <td>Content 1-6</td>
        <td>Content 1-7</td>
        <td>Content 1-8</td>
        <td>Content 1-9</td>
        <td>Content 1-10</td>
        <td>Content 1-11</td>
        <td>Content 1-12</td>
        <td>Content 1-13</td>
        <td>Content 1-14</td>
        <td>Content 1-15</td>
        <td>Content 1-16</td>
        <td>Content 1-17</td>
        <td>Content 1-18</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 2-1</td>
        <td>Content 2-2</td>
        <td>
         <div class="tooltipWrapper">
          <div>Hover me!</div>
          <div class="tooltip">Cool tips here!<br>Indeed, very cool tips<br>I do enjoy these tips</div>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>Content 2-4</td>
        <td>Content 2-5</td>
        <td>Content 2-6</td>
        <td>Content 2-7</td>
        <td>Content 2-8</td>
        <td>Content 2-9</td>
        <td>Content 2-10</td>
        <td>Content 2-11</td>
        <td>Content 2-12</td>
        <td>Content 2-13</td>
        <td>Content 2-14</td>
        <td>Content 2-15</td>
        <td>Content 2-16</td>
        <td>Content 2-17</td>
        <td>Content 2-18</td>
       </tr>
       
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
    </body>
```

My expected result would be that if you hover over the "Hover me" text, and have scrolled a bit to the right, that it would follow it, and show it above the scrollbar.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using 'bottom' instead of 'top'?

Comment: While that solves the issue for the bottom row, the top row will have the same issue, meaning it will be cut off from the top

Comment: Do you need this .contentWrapper{ overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;}? Because it hides your tooltip anyway ... except make it fixed.

Comment: Well I need that for the bottom scroll bar. Without it, it would add scrollbar to the bottom of the page.

Comment: then add height there for ex: .contentWrapper{height: 150px;}. It should be higher than the table .

Comment: I have content above and below this table, is there truly no way to somehow display that tooltip thingy above the scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution add margin-bottom to the table

```css
thead > tr > td {
      background-color: grey;
      width: 150px;
      height: 30px;
     }
     
     table{
      table-layout: fixed;
        margin-bottom:70px;
     }
     
     .tooltipWrapper{
      position:relative;
     }
     
     .tooltip{
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      background-color: green;
     }
     
     .tooltipWrapper:hover .tooltip{
      display:block;
     }
     
     .contentWrapper{
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
     }
```

```html
<div class="contentWrapper">
     <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 6</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
        <td>Column 9</td>
        <td>Column 10</td>
        <td>Column 11</td>
        <td>Column 12</td>
        <td>Column 13</td>
        <td>Column 14</td>
        <td>Column 15</td>
        <td>Column 16</td>
        <td>Column 17</td>
        <td>Column 18</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 1-1</td>
        <td>Content 1-2</td>
        <td>Content 1-3</td>
        <td>Content 1-4</td>
        <td>Content 1-5</td>
        <td>Content 1-6</td>
        <td>Content 1-7</td>
        <td>Content 1-8</td>
        <td>Content 1-9</td>
        <td>Content 1-10</td>
        <td>Content 1-11</td>
        <td>Content 1-12</td>
        <td>Content 1-13</td>
        <td>Content 1-14</td>
        <td>Content 1-15</td>
        <td>Content 1-16</td>
        <td>Content 1-17</td>
        <td>Content 1-18</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Content 2-1</td>
        <td>Content 2-2</td>
        <td>
         <div class="tooltipWrapper">
          <div>Hover me!</div>
          <div class="tooltip">Cool tips here!<br>Indeed, very cool tips<br>I do enjoy these tips</div>
         </div>
        </td>
        <td>Content 2-4</td>
        <td>Content 2-5</td>
        <td>Content 2-6</td>
        <td>Content 2-7</td>
        <td>Content 2-8</td>
        <td>Content 2-9</td>
        <td>Content 2-10</td>
        <td>Content 2-11</td>
        <td>Content 2-12</td>
        <td>Content 2-13</td>
        <td>Content 2-14</td>
        <td>Content 2-15</td>
        <td>Content 2-16</td>
        <td>Content 2-17</td>
        <td>Content 2-18</td>
       </tr>
       
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: as I said, I have content below and above this table, and I unfortunetaly cannot justify an empty space between the table and the scrollbar :( But thanks for all the ideas, I appreciate them

Comment: Than take a look at this article https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks really promising!